# Using Predicates on Array Objects in Swift returns Error

Tags: swift, nspredicate, key-value-coding

When I filter an array of custom Swift classes using a Predicate I get the error:

> *** NSForwarding: warning: object 0x78ed21a0 of class 'Plantivo1_6.Seed' does not implement methodSignatureForSelector: -- trouble ahead
>   Unrecognized selector -[Plantivo1_6.Seed valueForKey:]

If I remember correctly this would work in Objective-C. What's my mistake?

```
let names = ["Tom","Mike","Marc"]
println(names)
let searchPredicate = NSPredicate(format: "SELF CONTAINS[c] %@", "om")
let array = (names as NSArray).filteredArrayUsingPredicate(searchPredicate)
println(array)
println()

let mySeed1 = Seed()  // Seed is a class with a `culture` String property
let mySeed2 = Seed()
let mySeed3 = Seed()
mySeed1.culture = "Tom"
mySeed2.culture = "Mike"
mySeed3.culture = "Marc"

let mySeeds = [mySeed1,mySeed2,mySeed3]
println(mySeeds)
let searchPredicate1 = NSPredicate(format: "SELF.culture CONTAINS[c] %@", "om")
let array1 = (mySeeds as NSArray).filteredArrayUsingPredicate(searchPredicate1)
println(array1)
```

Answer (score 14, accepted):

Does your Seed class inherit from NSObject?

If not, this is the message you will get.

Solution:

```
class Seed: NSObject {
   ...
```

**Edit:**
stklieme is correct - to use NSPredicate, your object's class needs to implement `-valueForKey` as defined by the [NSKeyValueCoding protocol](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/Cocoa/Reference/Foundation/Protocols/NSKeyValueCoding_Protocol/index.html).  You can either define your own implementation of `-valueForKey`, or just make your class inherit from NSObject which takes care of that for you.

This is defined in [the Apple docs for NSPredicate](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/Cocoa/Conceptual/Predicates/Articles/pUsing.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40001794-CJBDBHCB),

> You can use predicates with any class of object, but the class must support key-value coding for the keys you want to use in a predicate.

Comment: Made some edits, does that explain it better?  It's just the way NSPredicate works internally to convert a string into a key that can be used to obtain a value from the class instance.

Answer (score 4):

In case if you don't want to inherit from `NSObject`, you can implement `value(forKey key: String) -> Any?` method by yourself:

```
extension Model {
    @objc func value(forKey key: String) -> Any? {
        switch key {
        case "id":
            return id
        // Other fields
        default:
            return nil
        }
    }
}
```

Note `@objc` prefix of the method: it's important, as it's allowing `NSPredicate` to see that the method is implemented. You'll still receive `does not implement methodSignatureForSelector:` crash without it.

Or, even better, make your objects to conform this protocol:

```
@objc protocol UsableInPredicate {
    @objc func value(forKey key: String) -> Any?
}
```

Comment: Worded for me. Thanks, Friend!!

Answer (score 1):

`valueForKey` is a key value coding method. Declare the class Seed as a subclass of NSObject which conforms to KVC

Comment: You need KVC for this predicate syntax, but you don't need KVO. KVO places additional requirements on a class that are not relevant here.

Answer (score 0):

Simply,

You need to inherit your model class by NSObject and your issue get fixed.

```
class Seed: NSObject {
   ...
}
```

**Reason:**
-valueForKey as defined by the NSKeyValueCoding protocol. You can either define your own implementation of -valueForKey, or just make your class inherit from NSObject